# Token based authentication for Rails JSON APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-api

I make API in rails. For normal authentication we use devise but in API how to implement devise for authentication.

```
gem 'devise_token_auth'
```

Someone prefer this this gem for authentication but there are no tutorial available for that.
How to implement authenitication in rails api?

Comment: This is question which I post but stack overflow deactivate my account :(

Answer (score 17):

Here is a good tutorial on [API authentication with devise_token_auth](http://www.developingandrails.com/2015/02/api-authentication-with-devisetokenauth.html).
Also, the [devise_token_auth  gem's github page](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) seems to have a very good documentation which should help you get started.

If you are looking for a good tutorial to understand the related concepts, [here is one](https://labs.kollegorna.se/blog/2015/04/build-an-api-now/) that has a thorough walkthrough of creating a Rails API with token-based authentication (Not using `devise_token_auth`, but useful to understand the concepts).

I also recommend you to take a look at the [JWT (JSON Web Token)](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt) which works very well with large scale Rails API. Here is another tutorial that explains how to build [Rails API Backed With JWT](http://rohitrox.github.io/2015/06/23/rails-api-backed-with-jwt/)

Answer (score 17):

The best thing you can do is to follow the [github tutorials](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#table-of-contents) which are most likely to be up-to-date.

First you should follow the [TLDR](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#configuration-tldr) part.
Note that the frontend developpers need to know about the [usage specification](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#usage-tldr).
Finally you want to go through the documentation. Here are some samples that might help:

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # Stuff
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users
  root to: "home#index"

  # The API part
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', skip: [:omniauth_callbacks]
      resources :stuff, only: [:index, :show]
    end
  end
end
```

**A controller**:

```
module Api
  class StuffsController < ApiController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    ...
  end
end
```

**API Controller**

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
end
```

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules.
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

Finally don't forget to configure the gem in the corresponding initializer.

Answer (score 4):

You can add attributes "authentication_token" to you table and use this gem:

https://github.com/robertomiranda/has_secure_token

in application_controller:

```
def authenticate_user!
  authenticate_user_from_token!
  super
end


def authenticate_user_from_token!
  User.find_by_authentication_token(user_token)
end

def user_token
  request.headers['X-AUTH-TOKEN'].presence || params['auth_token'].presence
end
```

Comment: Your solution absolutely saved me!
Just one simple modification, on authenticate_user! I had to modify the return value to authenticate_user_from_token! || super

Comment: It was this very simple and every1 seems referring to more gems. Even devise docs don't simple explain how I can auth myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my current project I have implemented [simple_token_authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication). It is pretty easy to implement and use as well.

Just add the following to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`

```
gem 'simple_token_authentication', '1.12.0'
```

Rest all of the steps are given in its documentation and pretty easy to follow too.