# How do I authenticate using Devise in a Rails REST API App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest, curl, devise

I'm creating a Rails app which have both a GUI part, and a REST/JSON-API.

The REST/JSON API is fairly simple, and the controller returns data like this:

```
def get_players
    @players = Player.all
    render json: @players
end
```

The GUI part of the app is using Devise for authentication, and it works fine.

Now I want to add authentication for the REST/JSON Api too, how do I do that?

Also, how do I test the REST API using curl when the Authentication is added?

---- edit ----

as it turns out, Devise wasnt necessary in this case. A home-cooked token-authentication method works for now. (token created when Player is created, and returned on correct e-mail/password combo).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After getting a few tips, I found a number of great sites. There are several ways to do this, however I don't know which one is best, but these sites help a long way:

- https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth (An extension to
  Devise)
- https://labs.kollegorna.se/blog/2015/04/build-an-api-now/
  (Manual way)
- [Token based authentication for Rails JSON APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560929/token-based-authentication-for-rails-json-apis) (SO Question)
- [Rails API : Best way to implement authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038475/rails-api-best-way-to-implement-authentication) (SO Question)
- [Rails API : Best way to implement authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038475/rails-api-best-way-to-implement-authentication?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: The labs.kollegorna url is dead, but I found the content here: https://github.com/kollegorna/labs.kollegorna.se/blob/master/source/posts/2015-04-09-build-an-api-now.html.md#adding-authentication